# Send emails using PHP mail function, configuration of the mail server

Tags: php, mysql, email, debian

I am making a web application (html + php + apache + mysql) which is on a Debian server, but when I try to send any mail using the php mail function, it is not simply sent me and throws an error. I guess I should install some smtp mail service. What do you recommend that is easy for a novice user settings?

I install a library called sendmail  in localhost that simulates that smpt service in WAMP server, but when I upload the code to the production server simply does not send mail.

I researched on some mail servers like postfix, but the information I get is confusing to me. I want to recommend me some effective guide, or any server that is easy to configure for a novice user in the subject.

sorry if the question is obvious, but I want effective information

Comment: You could install Postfix: `apt-get install postfix`

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Look at using a class like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to do this. You can configure any SMTP server you choose (including Gmail) so no need to install a mail service locally. It's a whole lot more flexible and less trouble than `mail()`

Comment: @MikeW you need to install any additional services?

Comment: @franvergara66 No need for additional services - that's the point. You can use an SMTP service elsewhere. You _can_ use a local service if you have one, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sending a mail you just simply need a smtp client that sends a mail to a destination. You don't need to install any smtp server for just sending a mail.

A smtp server is for receiving mails( and other stuff about mails).

All you need to make php sending a mail is to install a smtp client like sendmail

then edit php.ini to be like this:

```
sendmail_path= sendmail -t -i
```

EDIT: I guess debian has sendmail by default.